# Getting the error "expression did not evaluate to a constant" in VS 2015 after using dlib-19.1

Tags: visual-studio-2015, dlib

I am following the compilation procedure that has been posted on the dlib website.

I created an empty project called "bayes". I right-clicked on "Source Files", went to "Existing Item...", then added "source.cpp" to the "Source Files". I saw another question on the forum which stated the same error:
https://github.com/davisking/dlib/issues/194

I went to github and copied and pasted the code for source.cpp and matrix_utilities.h (The error is in this file) from github in my project. Despite that, I have been getting the same error when I run my code.

I right-clicked on the name of the project (bayes), clicked on "Properties", then went to "VC++ Directories" and then in "Include Directories" I added the path of the dlib-19.1 folder.

I even disabled the "Precompiled Headers" option under the "C/C++" heading. I don't understand why I am not able to run my code.

I compiled all the examples using CMake. I am able to open the examples.sln file and run most of the project files present there.

Why can't I run the code when I create an empty project, include all directories and copy and paste the same code in that project?

The error appears in the header file "matrix_utilities.h". It can be found in this link:
 (https://github.com/davisking/dlib/blob/master/dlib/matrix/matrix_utilities.h)

In this file, the error occurs in line 2688:

```
COMPILE_TIME_ASSERT(pixel_traits<P>::num > 0);
```

Comment: Does it happen when you just add a bit of dummy code, like hello world? If not, you're going to want to include your code here to get a better response (check out [MCVE])

Comment: @Jeff No. This happened when I copied and pasted one of the example codes given on the dlib website. I copied and pasted the code from the this link: (http://dlib.net/bayes_net_ex.cpp.html)

Comment: In that case you're definitely going to want to trim it down to the smallest bit of code that exhibits the error and include that code here - it's a bit of effort, but otherwise it's effort that an answerer is going to need to do, and you may well find that you can figure out the answer the problem yourself in the process (in which case it would be great if you posted the answer here as well for future users `:)`)

Comment: @Jeff I have posted more details in my question. I have posted where exactly I got the error.

Comment: @Jeff This is the ONLY error I get when I run the code. I don't get any other errors.

Comment: Visual Studio is well-known to have a problems to support C++11 standard and this lead to problems compiling dlib. Latest versions have some improvements. Try updating your compiler to the latest possible version - VC2015 Update3 now is latest

Comment: @Evgeniy I will update my compiler and see if I can build my code successfully or not. However, as I mentioned in the original question, after building the provided examples using CMake and opening the resulting "examples.sln" file on VS 2015, I was getting the proper output. I get an error only when I try to create an independent project using the dlib library.

Comment: @Evgeniy I don't understand why something like this should happen. Do you have any comments about this?

Comment: you have copied fresh "source.cpp" from gihub. i think you should get full source tree - may be changes are not inside this file. also if cmake examples are compiling well - try not to use "source.cpp". you have "dlib.lib" file - use it instead

Comment: @Evgeniy How do you suggest I include "dlib.lib"? Do I simply type #include "dlib.lib"? Additionally, do you suggest downloading the entire library from github again and re-compiling the examples? I previously downloaded the package from the main dlib website.

Comment: @Evgeniy The code is thankfully now working and I am getting the expected output. My code began compiling after I removed "source.cpp".

Comment: @Evgeniy Thank you for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I removed "sources.cpp", my code compiled properly.